# Cookies problems after enabling experimentalSessionAndOrigin in Cypress

Tags: cypress

Some cookies cannot be set after I have enabled experimentalSessionAndOrigin in my Cypress config file.

cypress.config.ts

```
export default defineConfig({
    e2e: {
        watchForFileChanges: false,
        retries: {
            runMode: 2,
            openMode: 0,
        },
        numTestsKeptInMemory: 15,
    },
});
```

Has anyone experienced something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue gets resolved in Cypress 10.10!

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/24149